# C# redrawing graphics on winform

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have a bitmap loaded onto a winform via an imagebox.  When I want to update the image I try as such:

```
imagebox.image = null;
draw();  //implements the drawing of the bitmap and assigns to the imagebox/winform
```

However, this will only work if I hide and then show the form again?  How can I get around this?

EDIT:  Problem resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the image property setter smarter.  For example:

```
private Image mImage;

public Image Image {
    get { return mImage; }
    set { 
        mImage = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Now the visible image refreshes automatically.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  I do have it working now.  I made a few silly mistakes with misplaced code re-creating the form and Imagebox when I re-drew the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making a call to `Invalidate(imagebox.Bounds);` at the end of the `draw()` method?

That should force a repaint, so you don't have to hide and show the form again.

Comment: Or you can just call `imagebox.Invalidate()`. Oh, and you don't need to generate a new image every time - just draw to the same one. Much more efficient.

Comment: The imagebox does invalidate.  I have included the code in my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this link [Bob Powell GDI+ FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20131226033137/http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.aspx). It's got some clear instructions to some of the GDI basics, this link goes to a PictureBox drawing example.

Basically you want to be attaching to the Paint event for the ImageBox and calling Invalidate() everytime you want a re-draw.

Comment: Since PictureBox is already good at redrawing its image whenever necessary, I don't think the Paint event is necessary. `Invalidate()` is though.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  will check it out.